# python random.choices() not giving equal number of elements even if we give equal weights

Tags: python, random

I want to create a random list with diffrent combinations of elements in the list. The count of each element appearing in the final list should same.

For example

```
>>> set_sizes = [0, 3, 6, 12]
>>> target_list = random.choices(set_sizes, weights = [1, 1, 1, 1], k= 40)
>>> print (target_list.count(0), target_list.count(3), target_list.count(6), target_list.count(12))

8 10 12 10
```

Here I was expecting the count of all elements will be 10 since I give equal weights. But it is not same always. How can I modify the code to get the equal count for all elements ? Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you want to shuffle a list, not choose from it. The entire point of choices is that each choice is independent from the others.

Answer (score 2):

You flip a coin 10 times, even through you have the same probability of getting the head with getting the tail each time, you don't always get 5 heads with 5 tails in the end. So the weighted random choice won't give what you want.

To get the target_list you want, simply create an ordered one, then shuffle it.

```py
import random
from itertools import chain

set_sizes = [0, 3, 6, 12]
k = 10
target_list = list(chain.from_iterable([x] * k for x in set_sizes))
random.shuffle(target_list)
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to build `target_list` that complicated. `target_list = set_sizes * k` is more efficient in just about every way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you're right, don't know what I was thinking when writing that line of code. 

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom and @ MisterMiyagi.  It worked for me.